# Does the resonance theorem in functional analysis have anything to do with resonance in mechanics?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I am now learning the following version of the resonance theorem.

> Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces. Let $\{T_\lambda:
> \lambda\in\Lambda\}$ be a family of bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$. If $\{T_\lambda:
> \lambda\in\Lambda\}$ is pointwise bounded on $X$, then $\{T_\lambda:
> \lambda\in\Lambda\}$ is uniformly bounded, i.e., $\sup\|T_\lambda\|<\infty$. **Or equivalently,** if $\sup\|T_\lambda\|=\infty$, then there exist $x\in B$ such that $\sup\|T_\lambda x\|=\infty$.

For those who don't think it can be called "resonance", see theorem 1.16 [here](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/15F-FA/Notes/FA09.pdf): My statement is equivalent to this.

Also, in physics, we know that resonance occurs when the imposed frequency onto an oscillating system equals its natural frequency.

**Question: How is the resonance theorem related to resonance in physics?**

Comment: @NateEldredge See theorem 1.16 here: http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/15F-FA/Notes/FA09.pdf. My statement is equivalent to this.

Comment: I've never heard it called "resonance..." Uniform boundedness, or Banach-Steinhaus.

Comment: A textbook source for the phrase "resonance theorem" is [Yosida's "Functional Analysis", p. 69](https://books.google.com/books?id=QqNpbTQwKXMC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). Interestingly, Yosida considers the resonance theorem as a corollary of the uniform boundedness thereom (which he states on the previous page).

Comment: The earliest source I've seen so far is a 1951 paper by I. S. Gal: [Sur la méthode de résonance et sur un théorème concernant les espaces de type (B)](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIF_1951__3__23_0/). I can't really read French, but as best I can tell: Gal attributes the method to Lebesgue but the word 'resonance' to a paper of Polya. See also Gal's abstract 173 to the [1951 AMS meeting](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183516692). PS: The author, also known Steven A. Gaal, was a professor in the UMN math department prior to his retirement.